# NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName not found

Tags: objective-c

I am using the following code to strikeThrough some text. But I keep getting that NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName is not declared. Where is it declared anyway?

```
NSMutableAttributedString *strikeThroughString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self];
    [strikeThroughString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                            value:@2
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [strikeThroughString length])];
```

Comment: It is declared in `UIKit`. Did you import this? And it is only available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi: NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName is part of UIKit. Your problem is your object must be a son of NSString, and in its header only import Foundation. In your implementation file (.m) add this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for some reason I could not find this in the documentation.